# Why don't the Clip Raster by Mask show proper band values/interpolated values in QGIS?

Tags: qgis, raster, gdal, clip

I'm trying to clip a raster interpolated data (using IDW) with a polygon in QGIS 3.10. It worked with the first file (as shown in the linked here [[desired Clipped (masked) layer](https://i.stack.imgur.com/57QoS.png)] and this would be the result I would want.
For the rest of the interpolated layers that I have (which all went through similar steps to the first layer mentioned), I used the exact same methods to Clip Raster by Mask Layer with the desired polygon. However, the resulting layer would not display any values. I have included the screenshots of what I did in order as below:

[image: Interpolated Layer]
[image: Polygon Layer - done in QGIS and saved as a .shp]
[image: Steps for Clipp Raster by Mask Layer_1]
[image: Continuation_Steps for Clip Raster by Mask Layer_2]
[image: Resulting Log_1]
[image: Resulting Log_2]
[image: Rendered values]

I've tried to reupload my datasets and redo the interpolations, but nothing has worked so far. I have checked the projections as well and all were in the desired projection. It just seems odd to me that these steps worked well before except for now. Not sure if it is a bug on the QGIS software or if something else went wrong.

Comment: In the dialog you are cutting by some Plot .shp layer but in the logs it is using some Clipped .shp data source, so I think that the problem may be in the cutline.